# How can I add permission to my app so it can use Office 365 Unified API (preview)

Tags: azure, office365

I'd like to use the new [Office 365 Unified API (preview)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/office-365-unified-api-overview) but it doesn't appear as one of the "other applications" I can add to my web app on my Azure portal. I'm already using "Office 365 Exchange Online" successfully but this new REST API doesn't even show up on my list. How can I get it to show up so I can add it?

Comment: Good question, I don't see it in my developer tenant either! I'll find out and post back.

Comment: Hi Uri,  Sorry for the issue here.  Can you provide your tenant details please?  Like your initial domain name (should be <something>.onmicrosoft.com), and we'll try and take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a regression in the platform. This has now been fixed.